# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when running default Asp.Net Core Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

When running the default `ASP.NET` Core webpage in Visual Studio 2019 using `IIS` express I cannot get I my browser launches (tried with Firefox, chrome, ie, edge) but I get an "`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`". When using the drop-down to run the the option that is the name of the project not the solution I get the following:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Philamon Hemstreet\source\repos\DefaultWebRazorPagesApp\DefaultWebRazorPages
```

[image]

After messing around a bit I got the debug section of the output to display:

```
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\Philamon Hemstreet\source\repos\DefaultWebRazorPagesApp\DefaultWebRazorPages\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DefaultWebRazorPages.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Collections.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\netstandard.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.ComponentModel.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Linq.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Threading.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Memory.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Private.Uri.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Text.Json.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Buffers.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.ObjectModel.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\Philamon Hemstreet\source\repos\DefaultWebRazorPagesApp\DefaultWebRazorPages\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DefaultWebRazorPages.Views.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Claims.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Console.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Private.Xml.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\System.IO.Pipelines.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.9\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Net.Sockets.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. 
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. 
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: C:\Users\Philamon Hemstreet\source\repos\DefaultWebRazorPagesApp\DefaultWebRazorPages
'DefaultWebRazorPages.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\System.Net.Security.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
The thread 0x5734 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2604 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1b48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x49d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x30d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x516c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x10fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x418 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3aec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x414c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xaa0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

The error is always the same although the threads differ (obviously). I havent messed with any setting other than my theme. I have all workloads installed on Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.7.6, this problem also existed on the previous version, and updating was one of my attemps to fix it. From the debug output it looks like '`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`' is probably the cause, however I'm not sure how to diagnose this. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does the browser work?  When was last time code worked?  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 (used for authentication with HTTPS) due to security issues.  This June Microsoft pushed a security update disabling TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and require using TLS 1.2/1.3.  The server may be refusing the connection due to TLS.  Best way of checking is using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Then compare working and non working apps checking the TLS version and the headers in the first request.  Also verify the status in the response (normally 200OK) and 400/500 if an error.

Comment: Have you tried turning off HTTPS redirect and seeing if the HTTP version of the site works? Also, try changing the port numbers for both sites to see if maybe you are getting a port conflict issue (something else using 5000/5001).

Comment: @IAmTimCorey Would I do that by editing the DefaultWebRazerPages.applicationUrl in the launchSettings.json?

Comment: @jdweng The browser works, I'm using it to post this right now. I'll load up wireshark and see if I can find anything helpful. I'm just a beginner so I'll see if I can figure that out.

Comment: @IAmTimCorey I changed it to port 1000 and got a port in use error so I don't think that works. Disabling HTTPS redirection doesn't change anything either.

Comment: The error is due to the server wanting HTTPS (secure) and you are trying to send HTTP (or a wrong security mode).  Most likely it has to do with the version of TLS (you can see in sniffer).  You version of Core is probably using TLS 1.0/1.1 which no longer allowed.  You must TLS 1.2/1.3.  It could be the version of the Operating System that you are using.  Could be old an doesn't support 1.2/1.3.  Or your client code need to specify 1.2 or 1.3 and you are not specifying and the old default value is being used.

Comment: @jdweng You are correct, when disabling HTTPS redirect in the initial project construction it works, I have an operating system to run. I will run it and see if it fixes the https redirect issue or not.